# How to Integrate Selenium IDE Tests Into Bamboo?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide, bamboo

I am looking for a way to run Selenium IDE tests in Bamboo. I want to avoid using something such as WebDriver because I want to keep my testing code light hence the IDE. I am also hoping to make this an automated process.

I have read about using a plug in called Charlotte or converting my Selenium IDE test into JUnit. I was wondering if there are other possible avenues.

Thank you for your replies.